# Express render function with callback return string and not HTML

Tags: node.js, express

I'm a nooby user of Nose.JS with express framework and I try to do an engine for HTML with this hierarchy :

```
<template>
  <layout>
    <view>
  </layout>
</template>
```

So, this is my server.js file (croped) :

```
var express = require('express')
        , http = require('http');
var app = module.exports = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

// Routes 
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var data = { /* Some data here */ };

    /* Probleme start here :
     * I want render the view HTML, 
     * then render the layout HTML with the view content,
     * then render the template to display
     */

    res.render('view', data, function(err, view) {
        data.view = view;
        res.render('layout', data, function(err, layout) {
            data.layout = layout;
            res.render('template', data);                
        });           
    });
});
```

Like I say on the code : 
I want render the view HTML, then render the layout HTML with the view content, then render the template to display. But **data.view** and **data.layout** are string and not HTML( like : `HEADER<br/>Menu<br/>`) , so if I put HTML code on this files I have the HTML code on the final page..

**-----[EDIT : Add .ejs files]-----**

**template.ejs**

```
<div><%= layout %></div>
```

**layout.ejs**

```
HEADER<br/>
Menu<br/>
<%= view %>
FOOTER
```

**view.ejs**

```
<p>View</p>
```

How can I get the result of HTML display on **data.view** and **data.layout** ?!

Thank you all and sorry for my English

Arthur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW this is what I've used to get layout support in Express 4 (tested with ejs):

```
/*
   Usage:
     Set a global/default layout with:
        app.set('view layout', 'bar');
     Set a layout per-render (overrides global layout) with:
        res.render('foo', { layout: 'bar' });
     Or disable a layout if a global layout is set with:
        res.render('foo', { layout: false });
     If no layout is provided using either of the above methods,
     then the view will be rendered as-is like normal.

     Inside your layout, the variable `body` holds the rendered partial/child view.

   Installation:
     Call `mpResponse();` before doing `require('express');` in your application.
*/

function mpResponse() {
  var expressResponse = require('express/lib/response'),
      expressResRender = expressResponse.render;
  expressResponse.render = function(view, options, fn) {
    options = options || {};
    var self = this,
        req = this.req,
        app = req.app,
        layout,
        cb;

    // support callback function as second arg
    if (typeof options === 'function')
      fn = options, options = {};

    // merge res.locals
    options._locals = self.locals;

    // default callback to respond
    fn = fn || function(err, str) {
      if (err) return req.next(err);
      self.send(str);
    };

    if (typeof options.layout === 'string')
      layout = options.layout;
    else if (options.layout !== false
             && typeof app.get('view layout') === 'string')
      layout = app.get('view layout');

    if (layout) {
      cb = function(err, str) {
        if (err) return req.next(err);
        options.body = str;
        expressResRender.call(self, layout, options, fn);
      };
    } else
      cb = fn;

    // render
    app.render(view, options, cb);
  };
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you, but how I can use that ?! And I'm using the version ~3.3.4 of express. :/

Comment: I have updated all packages, and use <%- and not <%= and it's work !! Oo?

Comment: Yeah, <%= escapes html. <%- does not. You can also do plain old regular code inside just <%. The [readme](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) has this and other information.